# SwiperJS Swiper Slider disable swipe on zoom but allow thumbnails to be clicked

Tags: swiper.js

Im trying disable the swipe functionality when the slider is zoomed, to make sure when the user drags the image to zoom, they are not going to trigger the swipe to the next or prev slide.

I tried to use allowTouchMove, but this only works on chrome, not on safari, firefox or edge.

Disabling prev and next slides on zoom works, with allowSlidePrev, allowSlideNext however when I click on the gallerys thumbnails it also disables clicks on there. Is there another way of disabling the swipe events, but allowing drag, and the gallery events being clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this before, and found no clues in the docs.

Notice that it's in fact really hard to swipe to other slide when the zoom is enabled (at least in the v6.0.4). So only if the attempt is long and strong enough, the swiper will swipe.

So... I think that this is the desired behavior of the maintainers.